# Sendgrid - Getting Error logs of Inbound Parse Webhooks

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendgrid

I have a successful setup of Sendgrid Inbound Parse points to a microservice Webhooks hosted in own data center. Now moved the same microservice to AWS EC2 instance and tested the webhooks through postman, post the QA created a one more Sendgrid Inbound Parse pointing to webhook hosted in the AWS.

Whenever send the mail to domain pointing AWS is not parsing whereas the local webhooks still working, I have cross-checked the MX records and entry everything is fine. I even tried swapping the local webhook mail domain to AWS but still no luck. To identify where actually the problem occurs I have searched for the Inbound Parse Error log in Sendgrid but didn't find it.

In this situation what kind of troubleshooting can be done in Sendgrid inbound parser flow.

Comment: Looks like there is not such thing. We were using Mailgun and had this logs and errors, migrated to Sendgrid and it's really worse, we do not get some letter and do not know why.